# `functools.update_wrapper` and `functools.wraps` copy more attributes over than expected

Tags: python, python-3.x, functools

I used [`functools.wraps`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) in a definition of a decorator to forward some attributes of a function to its wrapper. According to the documentation of `functools.wraps`, which is based on [`functools.update_wrapper`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functools.html#functools.update_wrapper), `functools.wraps` should assign the attributes, `__module__`, `__name__`, `__qualname__`, `__annotations__`, and `__doc__`, of the wrapped function to its wrapper by default. However, in my own usage, I see that `functools.wraps` forwards whatever attribute I define in the wrapped function as well.

```
import functools


def decorator(func):
    func.added_attr = 'I am added.'

    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper


@decorator
def foo():
    pass


print(foo.added_attr)
```

In the example above, `foo` eventually references the wrapper defined in `decorator`, yet this wrapper also has the `added_attr` defined in wrapped function. Can anyone explain this behavior which is not mention in the documentation?

Note: I tested the code above in Python 3.7 and 3.8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [`update_wrapper`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functools.html#functools.update_wrapper) docs (emphasis mine):

> The default values for these arguments are the module level constants `WRAPPER_ASSIGNMENTS` (which assigns to the wrapper function’s `__module__`, `__name__`, `__qualname__`, `__annotations__` and `__doc__`, the documentation string) and **`WRAPPER_UPDATES` (which updates the wrapper function’s `__dict__`, i.e. the instance dictionary).**

`func.added_attr = 'I am added.'` updates `func.__dict__`, which gets copied over by `update_wrapper`